# Complete mice function results don't match with $imp

Tags: r, missing-data, r-mice

I'm running an imputation in mice and something strange is happening with the complete function.

If I display the results using $imp from my object for a specific variable these are my results:

```
head(mice.train$imp$ViolentCrimesPerPop)
```

[image]

Now I run:

```
complete.train<-mice::complete(mice.train,1)
```

which should fill in the missing values in my data using the results from the first imputation

but when I check the first index listed in imp for example,

```
> complete.train$ViolentCrimesPerPop[1349]
[1] 366.34
```

Its not 113.81 like in my imp table.

Comment: I can't reproduce this using `imp = mice(nhanes, m=5, print=0); head(imp$imp$bmi) ; complete.train <- mice::complete(imp,1) ; complete.train$bmi[4]` . Is it possible that you re-ran the imputation, but the complete data is from an earlier run? Try in a fresh r session?  If not, can you add some data to your question that allows this to be replicated please. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem- because I sampled for the training data from my original dataset the rownames were all out of order . So those row numbers in that table aren't actually the row numbers.. Thanks!